# Combining multiple products to create another one with Javascript. Tips for an online shop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, e-commerce, product

I want to create an online shop where you can combine different coffee blends to make your own coffee blend. I saw another website that uses this logic, it is called - www.cubicocoffee.com

Basically, you can select the quantity of your coffee (12 oz, 16 oz or more) after which you can choose from different Single Origin coffee beans and combine them (20% from Brazil, 40% from Peru, 40% from Colombia - for example). After this step, you can select the roast and the grind and your coffee is good to go. I want to create a website that uses a similar logic when it comes to combining different products.

Does anyone know some tutorials or a practical approach towards this implementing the logic for the selection of products? Thank you!

Comment: Please read some tutorials of Javascript and HTML.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to check out the [select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) HTML element, which would include each product as an "option". You give each option a `value` attribute, and when someone selects one, the value is automatically "copied" to the value of the select element.

And you'll need [a counter](https://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-number.php) for how many units of the selected value to use.
To pass information to some kind of output/display field, you need to understand a bit about [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) and the `.innerHTML` attribute of HTML elements.

That should get you on your way. Good luck and happy coding.